# DIV element expands too whide

Tags: html, css

Ive got a typewriter effect which prints a welcome headline with. So in the `<div id="h1-id"></div>` is

```
<h1 class="typewriter headline-welcome">Good Morning Admin.</h1>
```

created.

My problem is, that the headline container expands too whide, that the right border (border-right: .15em solid white;) is printed far away from the welcome headline. [image: screenshot].
Ive tried to give it the display: inline property, but than the animation wouldnt start and is instantly expanded

I hope somebody of you might know why it expands at "maximum" width.
Im still pretty new to all this css and html so I hope to get some help here :D

css:

```
.typewriter {
overflow: hidden;
border-right: .15em solid white;
white-space: nowrap;
animation: typing 2s forwards;
font-size: 1.6rem;
width: 0;
```

}

@keyframes typing {
from {
width: 0
}

```
to {
    width: 100%
}
```

}

html

```
<body onload="welcome('@User.Identity.Name')">
          <div id="main" class="container">
            <div id="h1-id"></div>
          </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I think you're following this example; try making the element inline-block. Adding a reproduceable snippet in a web editor would also make it easier for others to suggest fixes. https://www.sitepoint.com/css-typewriter-effect/#:~:text=The%20Typewriter%20Effect%20Is%20Easy%20to%20Create&text=Here's%20the%20way%20the%20typewriter,%E2%80%9Ctypes%20out%E2%80%9D%20the%20text.

Comment: @Olaf Yea your right, thats my sample. I will mind it for the future with the reproducable snipped :D

Answer (score 0):

It's because `div`s are block elements by default: they will take up the entire width of the screen and push everything else to the next line.

You can make the `div` shrink to the width of it's contents by using

```css
width: fit-content;
```

Moreover, `h1` is also a block element by default, so animating it to `width:100%` is gonna make it take up the whole screen.
Change the keyframes to this:

```css
@keyframes typing { from { width: 0 }
    to {
        width: fit-content;
    }
}
```

And add `width: fit-content;` to your `div` as well.

Comment: Now the headline pops up after 2 seconds. But with the right div size.

Comment: @Hi1mNico Remove `width: fit-content;` from the div, does it solve the issue?

Comment: Sadly not. Keeps popping up